# Battery status not refreshing

Tags: power-management, indicator

It was working fine, but after upgrading Unity to last version, it is not refreshing anymore. The percentage and charging status remains on what it was on system startup.
acpi command in terminal, and even 'Power statistics' shows the right info.
battery indicator on the top bar and 'Power Settings' page are not refreshing.
even when battery percentage hits critical level, nothing happens till the system shutdowns.

[image]

Laptop: Lenovo G580 ; 
Ubuntu Version: 14.04 LTS ; 
Kernel: 3.13.0-30-generic .

Comment: I am using 14.04.3 and got the same issue. http://i.imgur.com/gQBpacT.jpg here is the evidence. But is not it weird no body answered? I think it is about an update.