# Battery status is not correct

Tags: battery, 18.10

I just got Thinkpad e480 and I upgraded BIOS to the last available and replaced Windows wizh Ubuntu 18.10. What I have found out is that the battery status does not work. It always shows 99%.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: [dupe1](https://askubuntu.com/q/488638/12864), [dupe 2](https://askubuntu.com/q/752929/12864), [dupe3](https://askubuntu.com/q/515920/12864), all with no answers so can't close this one. Is there a good canonical question that these can all be merged into?

Comment: I can add that when plug it to the charger, it says that is fully charged. I just hope it won't drain the battery and that I wount be able to use it anymore.

Comment: Well, I installed 18.04 and now it works as it should. I guess there is somekind of bug in 18.10.